# Объявление функций в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть ли разница между:

```
var square = function(x) {
  return x * x;
};
```

и

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
};
```

Читаю https://eloquent-javascript.karmazzin.ru/chapter3 и пытаюсь понять как правильно объявлять функции.

Comment: первый вариант - это function expression, а второй function declaration. https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions

Comment: и так и так можно объявлять

Comment: разница интересует именно там где `var square = function...` или вообще там где `XXX square = function...`? потому что ещё может быть например `let square = function....` и `const square = function....` и поведение в зависимости от `var/let/const` может чуть измениться

Comment: Разницы почти никакой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основное функциональное различие:

- В первом варианте (Function Expression) функцию можно будет использовать только после её объявления, она создается когда выполнение доходит до неё.
- Во втором (Function Declaration), функция будет доступна в любом месте кода (или в блоке кода, если функция объявлена в нём).

Comment: А как она может быть доступна до объявления ?

Comment: Вы можете объявить функцию в конце файла, а вызвать в начале.

Comment: можно еще про стрелочные упомянуть и про область видимости.