# разница между function declaration и function expression?(JS)

Tags: javascript

в чем разница между function declaration и fucntion expression?
я так понимаю declaration может принадлежать уже обьекту как его метод, а function expression уже сам по себе является обьектом. ?

ps:я только изучаю js

Comment: Вначале думал кинуть дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1236045/191482  потом подумал, а может кто-то распишет каноничный ответ более подробно и шире?

Comment: это понятно. меня интересует другое ,Можно ли var abv=function abv() { return 3 }; считать обьектным выражением ? спасибо за предыдущий ответ

Comment: хм, а что значит объектное выражение?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions

Comment: var abv=function abv() { return 3 };  console.log(typeof abv);

Comment: typeof (abv) ; - function. можно ли считать обьектом ?

Answer (score 0):

Каноничный ответ на основной вопрос кроется [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-expressions).

- Функции – это значения. Они могут быть присвоены, скопированы или объявлены в другом месте кода.
- Если функция объявлена как отдельная инструкция в основном потоке кода, то это Function Declaration.
- Если функция была создана как часть выражения, то считается, что эта функция объявлена при помощи Function Expression.
- Function Declaration обрабатываются перед выполнением блока кода. Они видны во всём блоке.
- Функции, объявленные при помощи Function Expression, создаются, только когда поток выполнения достигает их.

По дополнительному вопросу

```
var abv=function abv() { return 3 }; 
console.log(typeof abv); // function
```

> Функции в JavaScript
>
> [Функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) - ключевая концепция в JavaScript. Важнейшей особенностью
> языка является первоклассная поддержка функций​ (functions as
> first-class citizen). Любая функция это объект, и следовательно ею
> можно манипулировать как объектом

Comment: Если функция была создана как часть выражения, то считается, что эта функция объявлена при помощи Function Expression.это если мы строим обьект ?

Comment: declaration не относят к обьектам ?

Comment: Читайте ниже Любая функция это объект